# Can we have same cut?

Tags: optimization

In Benders decomposition algorithm, we first solve a master problem which provides us with a solution vector. We then use this vector to construct a subproblem. For a minimization problem, subproblems give an upper bound .

if different between upper bound and lower is big , then we add a Benders cut to remove this point.

this Benders (optimality) cut is used to remove such point from master problem.
Is it possible  we have  identical optimality  cut  in different repeats in the benders decomposition method?

I'm a bit confused,
 I did not understand well
I think 
Only when we  reached to the optimal solution, cut can be repeated. Because cut remove some point  that is not proper, when cut related  meant that point  is optimal

Right?

Comment: It is not clear what you are talking about. Try to add a few sentences about the problem you are solving.

Comment: @Benedict William John Irwin hello , my question is general , is it possible we have same cut in  different  iteration  on  benders method?

Comment: @kenkavaza See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427735/benders-decomposition/2427863#2427863